# Open Developer Tools console by default in IE11 (without pressing F12 explicitly)

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache

I have a bug which is only on IE11 and occurs only when the site is opened via a link. The page is blank. But, if I refresh, the page loads correctly. I feel there would be some error in the developer tools console but my problem is that by the time I press F12, the call is already done and nothing shows up in the log. Is there some way I can open IE and developer tools tab will be open by default ? Or any other process by which I can see if there are any errors on the log ?

Also, since this is a bug only for HTTPS, I realised that if I have fiddler running and the "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" checked, things work fine. If it is not checked, same blank page error.

Comment: Does that issue occur when you paste page URL in address bar and hit enter?

Comment: Nope. Does not occur. Only for direct link clicks.

Comment: Check [IE11 intermittently not loading pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914473/ie11-intermittently-not-loading-pages) discussion. In earlier versions of IE there was a way to log events to Windows Event Viewer. However, I wasn't able to make it works in IE 11. Check [Interent Explorer Log is empty always](https://superuser.com/questions/846843/interent-explorer-log-is-empty-always) discussion and [Finding Security Compatibility Issues in Internet Explorer 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250493(v=VS.85).aspx) article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enable Always record developer console messages feature and open Developer Tools after browser loads the page.

To enable Always record developer console messages go to Tools, Internet Options, Advanced tab, Browsing section and check Always record developer console messages:
[image: How to enable Always record developer console messages guide]

After you opened Developer Tools, you may need to wait for some time before browser displays all recorded messages. In my case is was about 30 seconds. For more information check [Using the Console to view errors and debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255006(v=vs.85).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: I don't see any such option the IE settings. Probably because this is a Windows 8.1 update (as mentioned in the link you gave) and the machine I am working on is a Windows server 2012 R2

Comment: This feature is available on Windows Server 2012 R2. Which version of IE 11 do you have?

Comment: After upgrading my IE version I can see the checkbox. Thanks. Unfortunately, no error messages were logged in the console.